# "OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded": parse large json file with java

Tags: java, json, parsing, garbage-collection

I try  to parse large json file (more 600Mo) with Java.
My `json` file look like that:

```
{
    "0" : {"link_id": "2381317", "overview": "mjklmklmklmklmk", "founded": "2015", "followers": "42", "type": "Gamer", "website": "http://www.google.com",  "name": "troll", "country": "United Kingdom", "sp": "Management Consulting" },
    "1" : {"link_id": "2381316", "overview": "mjklmklmklmklmk", "founded": "2015", "followers": "41", "type": "Gamer", "website": "http://www.google2.com",  "name": "troll2", "country": "United Kingdom", "sp": "Management Consulting" }
    [....]

    "345240" : {"link_id": "2381314", "overview": "mjklmklmklmklmk", "founded": "2015", "followers": "23", "type": "Gamer", "website": "http://www.google2.com",  "name": "troll2", "country": "United Kingdom", "sp": "Management Consulting" }
}
```

and my code looks like that:

```
public class dumpExtractor {

    private static final String filePath = "/home/troll/Documents/analyse/lol.json";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        // read the json file
        FileReader reader = new FileReader(filePath);
        JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) jsonParser.parse(reader);
        Iterator<JSONObject> iterator = jsonObject.values().iterator();

        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        JSONObject jsonChildObject = iterator.next();
        System.out.println("==========================");
        String name = (String) jsonChildObject.get("name");
        System.out.println("Industry name: " + name);

        String type = (String) jsonChildObject.get("type");
        if (type != null && !type.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("type: " + type);
        }

        String sp = (String) jsonChildObject.get("sp");
        if (sp != null && !sp.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("sp: " + sp);
        }
        System.out.println("==========================");
        }
        System.out.println("done ! ");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } 
    }
}
```

I 've got this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
    at java.util.HashMap.createEntry(HashMap.java:897)
    at java.util.HashMap.addEntry(HashMap.java:884)
    at java.util.HashMap.put(HashMap.java:505)
    at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.parse(Unknown Source)
```

How I can fix that ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The problem is the complete object is too huge. Try reading that file line by line and parsing each of the nested objects separately.

Comment: Can you add the lines with your import statements so we can see what Parser you're using?

Comment: @CarlosBribiescas The stack trace shows it: `org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser`

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/memleaks002.html#tahiti1150092

Comment: How much RAM do you allow the JVM to allocate? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14763079/what-are-the-xms-and-xmx-parameters-when-starting-jvms

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have to read huge JSON Files you can't mantain in memory all informations. 
Extending memory can be a solution for a file of 1 Gb. If the files tomorrow is a 2 Gb Files?

The right approach to this problem is to parse the json element by element using a streaming parser. Basically instead of loading the whole json in memory and creating a whole big object representing it you need to read single elements of the json and converting them to objects step by step.

[Here](http://javarevisited.blogspot.it/2015/03/parsing-large-json-files-using-jackson.html) you find a nice article explaing how to do it with jackson library.

Answer (score 2):

You have two choices:

1. Give more memory to the Java program by specifying the `-Xmx` argument, e.g. `-Xmx1g` to give it 1 Gb of memory.
2. Use a "streaming" JSON parser. This will scale to infinitely large JSON files.

[json-simple](https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/) has a streaming API. See https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/wiki/DecodingExamples#Example_5_-_Stoppable_SAX-like_content_handler

There are other libraries with good streaming parser, e.g. [Jackson](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonStreamingApi).

Answer (score 1):

Increase the JVM heap space by setting the environment variables :

```
SET _JAVA_OPTIONS = -Xms512m -Xmx1024m
```

But it cant be a permanent solution as your file can be increased in future